# How can I show images and videos on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, video, c++, image-viewers

I am using an ARM-based RaspberryPi-like board, and Ubuntu Server on it. I'd like to write a C++ program that can show some images and videos. I mean I can include some libraries above my program and then call functions in C++ code to do that. But maybe there are better options inside the Linux and I can use them for this purpose? 
Less CPU/memory consumption is what I am looking for...

My goal is to build a robot that when user turns on it, it only shows my logo and then shows a picture and waits for user command, then it shows an image or video related to users command and then shows default image again and this will continue. I have  explained this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400096/how-to-create-a-lite-graphical-ability-for-linux-server) more specifically.

Comment: This is a programming question, better asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I'd say it's more of an environment issue. Might be on topic on [SO], but it's fine here too.

Answer (score 4):

- The [MagickWand API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) is the recommended interface between the C programming language and the ImageMagick image processing libraries. I installed libgtk-3-dev and tried running [your code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401922/failed-to-connect-to-mir-failed-to-connect-to-server-socket-no-such-file-or-di) with it on Ubuntu 16.04 and it also worked.
- [VLC-Qt](https://vlc-qt.tano.si/) is a free library used to connect Qt and libvlc libraries. It contains core classes for main media playback and some GUI classes for faster media player development. The VLC-Qt core library connects to libvlc and controls playback. The entire libvlc library is completely wrapped into C++/Qt.

ImageMagick, libgtk-3-dev, VLC, libvlc packages and Qt packages can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.

To install a minimal X window system on Ubuntu Server run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

Next install a window manager:

```
sudo apt-get install openbox
```

Comment: Are imageMagic and libvlc installed by default on Ubuntu-server? If not, are they better choice than GTK, or maybe OpenCV?

Comment: Very thanks for edited post. So if it's possible, you consider my other question too please: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400096/how-to-create-a-lite-graphical-ability-for-linux-server

Comment: see this please: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401922/failed-to-connect-to-mir-failed-to-connect-to-server-socket-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: I visited your link and copied your code into a file named test.c. Then I compiled it with the command from my answer at this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/939243/how-to-install-latest-gtk-for-creating-c-programs/939276#939276 and ran the executable test file with the command `./test 1.png` and it ran in Ubuntu 16.04 without errors.

Comment: I attached a keyboard to my board and in it's terminal executed my program and it worked!